# SSRS How to keep drill-down from showing up in the Web Service URL

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have what seems like a very simple problem.  We have built a project with 3 reports using SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services) 2012.  One main report and 2 drill-down reports that are called from the main project.  Something like this:

- Main Report
- Details 1
- Details 2

When Details 1 or Details 2 are called with the necessary parameters from the Main Report, everything works correctly.  The problem is the when I go to the Web Service URL which is where the reports are published, the users see the 2 drill-down reports that are not relevant when run by themselves.  What I need to try to do is hide the Details 1 and Details 2 from the Web Service URL so that they don't show up.  I can't figure out how/where to do that.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Web services URL is also known as the Reporting Services Interface and usually has an address similar to `http://servername/reportserver/`. This interface is not intended for user access. You can't hide reports in this interface.

The Report Manager, default URL of `http://server/reports/`, is intended for user access. In the properties for reports, data sources, and folders you will find a check box labelled "Hide in tile view." This is as close as you can get to what you are describing without building your own front end.